# jslint, jsdoc and rhino integration to run from command line?

Tags: javascript, rhino, jslint, jsdoc

I have to test all my js files through command line in development environment before push to production.how should i integrate this 3? so that i can run

```
jslint jsfile.js or jslint jsfile1.js jsfile2.js etc
```

similarly jsdoc to produce my jsdoc style api documents.

any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) useful to help you with this.  In particular, you can automate this step as part of an ant build.

Comment: I am looking for a Rhino based solution ..since JsLint and JsDoc both runs using Rhino...